# How do you use the tf.data pipeline to allow dataset selection and batching?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use the tf.data input pipeline to allow selection of the dataset at runtime while batching the data. The following should allow me to run InitTrain/InitTest to select which dataset to use:

```
TrainData = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(TrainGenerator,tf.float32)
TestData = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(TestGenerator,tf.float32)

DataIterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(tf.float32)
DataNext = DataIterator.get_next()
InitTrain = DataIterator.make_initializer(TrainData)
InitTest = DataIterator.make_initializer(TestData)
```

I can use the following to get a padded batch if not using the iterator:

```
TrainData.padded_batch(1000,someshape)
```

How can I batch my data while retaining the ability to select the input data source?

A possible workaround would be to create a new from_generator dataset and create a generator that calls sess.run on DataNext to create a dataset that can be batched however this would result in allot of run calls so I doubt this is the way it was meant to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your datasets functions independently of the other, and the iterator switches between detests based on which initializer you use.  So if you wanted to batch one dataset but not the other you would use:

```
TrainData = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(TrainGenerator,tf.float32)
TrainData = TrainData.batch(100)

TestData = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(TestGenerator,tf.float32)

DataIterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(tf.float32)
DataNext = DataIterator.get_next()
InitTrain = DataIterator.make_initializer(TrainData)
InitTest = DataIterator.make_initializer(TestData)
```

Incidentally you can also use the fact the two pipelines are different to (if you wanted to) do different mappings for each dataset.  So for example you could use batch normalization on the train data but then no normalization on the Test data (if you had already normalized across the entire data set).